# jQGrid Pager_left width too small with few columns

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I have a Model, View, and Controller that will automatically convert a `DataTable` to a `jQGrid`. It works as expected, unless the `DataTable` has only 2 columns. The data is rendered as expected, but the `Pager_Left` is forced to a width of 20px regardless of the screen or grid size.

I have tried to step through the code to find where this is happening, but cannot see anywhere I am making it happen.

When I am stepping through, it is after this line of code:

```
jQuery("#" + "@Model.GridId").jqGrid('navGrid', '#' + '@Model.PagerId', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: false });
```

that the `Pager_Left` shrinks. If I comment out the code, it displays as expected, but then I don't get my custom buttons in the pager.

Exact same code with a wider table produces the expected results. I think `jQGrid` has some "feature" that tries to adjust the pager when there aren't many columns, but I don't know how to turn it off.

I can do this:

```
$('#' + '@Model.PagerId' + '_left').css('width', '');
```

right after the offending code and it display as expected, but I would rather not hack it with a `jQuery` call to remove the style after it is added.

How do I turn off the "feature", or override it using proper `jQGrid` settings?

Comment: What is your main question? I use the hack with removing `width` property on left pager myself too in situations when initial width of the grid is too small. Do your search for the places of the code which produces the CSS inline style? It's side effect, not a "feature". No special option exist in jqGrid to turn off the "feature". If you want to post bug report you should do this on [trirand forum](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs). Only Tony, the only official developer of jqGrid, have right to modify the original code  of jqGrid.

Comment: My "main question" was how to do it without the hack. However, it sounds like the hack is my best option for now.

Comment: There are two places of jqGrid code where one makes some kind of "feature detection". See [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1950-L1961) (and especially [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1957)) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2139-L2147)). As the result `width` will be set in the case where it is not needed. I find removing of `width` style of left pager the way without any side effect. So I find it good enough.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks. This is helpful. I have submitted a bug and will use my hack for now.

Comment: @Oleg, will you post your answer as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places of jqGrid code where one makes some kind of "feature detection". See [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1950-L1961) (and especially [the line‌​](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L1957)) and [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2139-L2147)). As the result `width` will be set in the case where it is not needed.

I find removing of `width` style of left pager the way without any side effect. So I find it good enough.