# jqgrid : pager alignment

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

by default pager centered at the center position.
But when I'm providing fixed width size for my columns then the pager position goes to left.

But I want ti to be center align. How can I do that ?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that the problem can be fixed by removing `width` from the left part of the pager. If the pager have for example the name `mypager` then the `id` of the left pager is `mypager_left`. So I suggest you to try the following:

```js
$("#mypager_left").css("width", "");
```

More details why the width will be set in some situations you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26429928/315935).